# Enter on mac safari takes two chars but shows only one char is used

Tags: jquery, line-breaks

I am using this jquery

http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/enforceform.shtml

It shows me wrong char count on mac safari when i hit enter key.Its like enter takes two chars but shows only one in displaying the text

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This discrepancy is because of different line endings name \r or \n or \r\n. From my past experience I believe the following is the behaviour you should expect from browsers.

```
Chrome (Windows and OS X) counts enter as 2 distinct characters
Firefox (Windows and OS X) counts enter as 1 single character
IE (Windows) counts enter as 1 single character
Safari (OS X) counts enter as 2 distinct characters
```

To fix this, you can either replace \r\n with \n whenever it changes.

```
$("#comment").val($("#comment").val().replace(/\n\r/g, '\n'))
```

Or use some other jquery scripts that already does it for you.

e.g.: http://pioul.fr/jquery-maxlength